# Wordpress + Ajax page loading + Gravity forms + Gravity forms page break

Tags: ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravity, gravityforms

I have this set up at the moment:

A WordPress site, I'm using something similar to http://barbajs.org/ 
So every page content is loaded through ajax to a `<main></main>` tag.

In one of the pages (contact page), I have a gravity form and is using a page break. The form is made into steps and each step is loaded inside the page. Everything is working if the first page that I load is that page (contact page), but as soon as I go to a different page and come back, or if I go to contact page from a previous page the form doesn't work anymore.

Any ideas on how to fix it. 
This is the code part:

Wordpress: WYSIWYG with shortcode

```
[gravityform id="2" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```

On load, I have this:
`jQuery('#gform_wrapper_2').show()` (This is the only thing that works), so I don't get a black page.

If I click on next step (it doesn't load next step) and I've tried this:
This I found on the documentation or in the next button under `onclick = "..."`

```
jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_conditional_logic', [2, null, true])
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_conditional_logic', function(event, formId, fields, isInit){} )
jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [2, 1]) 
jQuery("#gform_target_page_number_2").val("2");  
jQuery("#gform_2").trigger("submit",[true]);
```

I will need something like `gform.init()` ideally :D or something similar that lets me bind the form again.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it live somewhere?

Comment: Your description is decent enough but I need to see this live so I can debug the code and see what's going wrong. Or, at least, can you post the javascript loading code snippet and how is it triggered?

Comment: You may also consider checking theme/plugin conflicts as described in their gravity forms docs https://docs.gravityforms.com/testing-for-a-themeplugin-conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit into gravity form plugin I was able to fix this.

So here is what I did.. hope it helps somebody in the future (not sure if the best solution but it works):

So the "main" idea is that barba or whatever you are using (in my case biggie) is making an ajax call for a new page and you will have something like a ready / newPageReady function, in here you make a new ajax call to get your form.

JS: (Given that gform uses jquery you can use it)

```
 ready(done) {

   ajax.get(APP.AJAX_URL + '?action=get_form', {

      success: (object) => {

      //console.log(object.data)

      jQuery('.main-content-wrapper').append(object.data)
      jQuery('body #gform_wrapper_2').show()

    }
  })
}


addEvents() {

  // this will check everytime a form is loaded 

   jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', this.gform)

}


gform(event, form_id, current_page) {

   //Here the form is loaded but not showed.. you can do something like this

    TweenMax.fromTo('.gform_wrapper', 1.2, {autoAlpha: 0}, {autoAlpha:1})
}
```

Functions.php

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_form', 'get_form' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_form', 'get_form' );

 function get_form() {

     gravity_form( id_of_your_form,false, false, false, false, true );

    die();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's the right solution but I managed to do something like `gform.init()` by calling script tags under the form with an `eval()`. Theses scripts are inserted after each form by the plugin.

For example, after you change your page with ajax, do something like this :

```
// After changing page with ajax :

var scripts = myNewForm.querySelectorAll('script'); // where "myNewForm" is the container including the new form added after an ajax call  

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) { // "For" loop in case there is more than one script added by the plugin

    eval(scripts[i].innerHTML); // --> this will init the new form
}
```

Be sure to call this only after an ajax call.